# Base Conversion with a decimal point in C++

Tags: c++, base-conversion

I am struggling to come up with an algorithm in C++ that converts a number with a decimal point from a base to any other base. I have successfully been able to write a function that converts numbers without decimal points to any desired base.

```
double  getBase10 (string number, int CurrentBase){
    double converted =0;
    for (int i =0; i < number.length(); i++){
        converted += pow(CurrentBase, -1 * (number.length() - i -1)) * getNumber(number[i]);
    }
    return double converted;
}
```

This is the function I have so far as requested by Mooing Duck.

Comment: Can you show the code you have without decimals?  I bet it can be trivially expanded for decimals

Comment: Unrelated, it makes little sense to "convert a number... from a base..." because values don't have bases.  _Numeric representations such as strings_ have bases, but numbers themselves don't have bases.  So are you converting from a string-represented-number in one base to a string-represented-number in another?  Or just from a value to a string-represented-number?

Comment: Whoa, this converts a string-represented-number in a base and converts that to a value.  Misleading because nothing in this code has anything to do with base10.

Comment: Also is there a reason to not be using `stringstream` or `boost::lexical_cast` or somesuch?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you could accomplish this task using stringstream?

Comment: Fair point, stringstream and lexical cast only work with specific bases.  There's stuff prexisting somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand. I am passing in a number and the base that the number is in. How would stringstream help in this situation?

Comment: I hadn't thought it through the first time.  `stringstream` can only read in base 10 and base 16, no others.  So it doesn't help this situation.  Neither does `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: Also, this code fails for `getBase10("14",10)`.  Get it to work right before you expand it.

Comment: It works perfectly fine with any base conversions that is a whole number if you take off the negative exponent in the power function.

Comment: Skip the decimal point - convert as if it weren't there - but count how many digits were to the right of it (say, `n`). The intermediate result is a whole number (which you say you already know how to do). At the end, simply divide by `pow(base, n)`. In other words, `3.14 == 314 / 10^2`.